# Bootstrapped Leiningen plugin development in Clojure

Tags: plugins, clojure, leiningen

I am attempting to write a Leiningen plugin that is compatible with the latest release and next 2.0 version, but am having troubles running the plugin on itself. What I mean by this is that I would like to write the codes and then run `lein foo` to run the latest version of plugin code on the plugin code itself.  My project.clj file is below:

```
(defproject foo "0.0.0"
  :description "simple version for experiment"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [fs "1.1.2"]]
  :source-path "src/clj")
```

In the src/clj/leiningen folder I have a simple foo.clj file that just calls the function in src/clj/bar/foo-test.clj that prints the contents of the project directory. However, whenever I run `lein foo` it says not able to find foo.clj on CLASSPATH. If I move all files from src/clj to src and remove `:source-path` directive then it runs the right thing in foo.clj but then complains about fs.clj not found on CLASSPATH. I would have hoped this would be easier without the need for adding the foo dependency to project.clj and `lein install,deps,foo` between changes, but that is currently only way I make it work.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PLUGINS.md, `:source-path` is now `:source-paths` in Leiningen 2.0, and should contain a vector instead of a direct string.

Another potential error is that you don't have `:eval-in-leiningen true` in the project file. I believe that is necessary to inherit the CLASSPATH of leiningen itself. I'm not certain if that is triggering any problems with finding `fs.clj` though.